# Where to start troubleshooting with "duplicate symbol"?

Tags: c++, sfml, duplicate-symbol

I'm learning C++ on Mac and trying to follow along with the SFML Game Development by Example book.
Any obvious places to start looking for problems when I get:

```
duplicate symbol __Z2dpi in:
    /var/folders/f1/4ddx4sk171v4hp6s50c93zh40000gn/T/sfgamewindow-374355.o
    /var/folders/f1/4ddx4sk171v4hp6s50c93zh40000gn/T/statemanager-3f5acc.o
[ plus 34 more similar duplicate symbols]
```

?
Would that have anything to do with #including?

This is my make command:

```
cd ~/Programming/CPP;
clang++  -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++14 \
-o Testgame         \
-I. -I/Users/johnrebekah/Programming/SFML\ source/include \
-I/Users/johnrebekah/Programming/CPP/gameheaders \
-lsfml-window.2.5.1     \
-lsfml-system.2.5.1     \
-lsfml-graphics.2.5.1   \
 "/Users/johnrebekah/Programming/CPP/gameheaders/sfgamewindow.cpp" \
 "/Users/johnrebekah/Programming/CPP/gameheaders/statemanager.cpp" \
 "/Users/johnrebekah/Programming/CPP/gameheaders/introstate.cpp" \
 "/Users/johnrebekah/Programming/CPP/gameheaders/eventmanager.cpp" \
 "/Users/johnrebekah/Programming/CPP/gameheaders/game.cpp" \
 "/Users/johnrebekah/Programming/CPP/testgame.cpp" \
```

All of the listed duplicate symbols are from the first file in the list of cpps in the make command, paired with various other of the cpp files...

Comment: Do you have a symbol called `dpi` somewhere?  If so, please show the containing file.

Comment: None of the symbols listed are intelligible to me, they aren't anything that I wrote in my source files. Any chance they are from the SFML library?

Comment: Wait, I did write a debug print function called dp... I'm going to try commenting that out...

Comment: According to https://demangler.com/  `__Z2dpi` is a function called "dp" that takes an integer.  And the error message says it is defined in both  /Users/johnrebekah/Programming/CPP/gameheaders/sfgamewindow.cpp and 
/Users/johnrebekah/Programming/CPP/gameheaders/statemanager.cpp

Comment: I commented out a top-level function in a header of my own that I included, and now the duplicate symbol warning is gone but I have this:``` ld: can't open output file for writing: Testgame, errno=21 for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1```

Comment: Seems that some functions are defined in some header but not inline and not static so those violate one definition rule.

Comment: Is there a keyword I need to add before the function for it to compile correctly?

Comment: If it is in header then keyword is inline. If you have functions with same name in different cpps then keyword is static.

Comment: Don't define non-inline functions in header files. Declarations go to header files. Definitions go to the .cpp files. Also look up "name mangling".

Comment: Thank you all for the help, got it running...

Comment: Note: Compiling all the `.cpp` files at once is asking for trouble. The normal process is to build each individually, then link together for the final library or executable.